# Windows Server 2019 extremely slow lately, can't figure out why

Tags: hard-drive, performance, sata, windows-server

Over the past few weeks my Windows 2019 Server has been getting slower and slower.  It's a development machine and I'm the only one on it.  It's an Intel i7-4790 3.6ghz, 16gb RAM, one WD 500gb and one Seagate 1tb 3/6gb SATA drives plugged into the 6gb SATA ports on the motherboard. I've done disk cleanups, scandsk's, defrags, checked virus scanner, switched SATA cables and ports.  I've downloaded and ran Western Digital and Seagate's disk checkers and they check out fine.  I thought it might have been when I added the 1tb drive that it started slowing down but I disconnected it and it's still slow. I reinstalled VS even though that's not the only thing slow.

As an example of "slow", it will take a little over 5 minutes to load a project in Visual Studio 2022 Community while the same project and VS takes < 40 seconds on other computers half the RAM and power.  There is no one else on the server but me.  I start the program where is is no CPU, disk, or network activity (disabled). When VS loads the project, CPU is 2-3%, Memory goes up a gig to 35% used, disk is 100% "active" and transfers at a max of about 2mb. After the project is loaded, everything goes back to zero.

I am out of ideas.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the SMART data of the disk and the Event Viewer?

Comment: Checked SMART data but not the events... nothing there when I did

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Tried in safe mode and same thing... still slow.

Comment: Might be the disk, but you'll need to replace it in order to be sure. In any case, ensure to have good backups.

Comment: Well, in the end that's what I did.  Switched to an SSD and now it's superfast so I'm guessing the disk was dying.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was likely a dying disk.

When the disk was replaced, the problem was solved.